# using livu (lib) with objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, live-streaming

I am creating an application in which i have to stream video over RTMP protocol. I googled and found Livu Library downloaded the library files but didn't get enough help how to integrate that library in my Xcode project.

Anyone please suggest some links or help me for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What aspect of the integration are you having problems with?  Is it adding the static library to your project or actually using the Livu library itself?  If it's the former then there are already many SO questions on this subject.

Comment: i am stuck in using Livu Library as i didn't found steps/instruction to use it....